# Error with RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

I can't get my code work
I'm trying to get a list of my database activities.

A lot of research here and none of the answers helped me

My Adapter

```
public class AtividadesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AtividadesAdapter.AtividadesViewHolder> {


    private Context mCtx;
    private List<Atividades> atividadesList;

    public AtividadesAdapter(Context mCtx, List<Atividades> atividadesList) {
        this.mCtx = mCtx;
        this.atividadesList = atividadesList;
    }


    @Override
    public AtividadesViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mCtx);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.atividades_lista, null);
        return new AtividadesViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(AtividadesViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Atividades atividades = atividadesList.get(position);
        holder.textViewAtividade.setText(atividades.getAtividade());
        holder.textViewData.setText(String.valueOf(atividades.getDataPrevista()));
        holder.textViewHora.setText(String.valueOf(atividades.getHora()));
        holder.textViewDestinatarios.setText(atividades.getDestinatarios());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return atividadesList.size();
    }

    class AtividadesViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView textViewAtividade, textViewData, textViewHora, textViewDestinatarios;

        public AtividadesViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textViewAtividade = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewAtividade);
            textViewData = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewData);
            textViewHora = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewHora);
            textViewDestinatarios = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewDestinatarios);
        }
    }
}
```

My activity

```
public class AtividadesActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String URL_ATIVIDADES = "";
List<Atividades> atividadesList = new ArrayList<>();
public RecyclerView recyclerView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.atividadesrecyclerview);
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        loadAtividades();
    }

    private void loadAtividades() {
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL_ATIVIDADES,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response);
                            for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject a = array.getJSONObject(i);
                                Log.d("Valores", a.getString("Atividade"));
                                atividadesList.add(new Atividades(
                                        a.getInt("idAtividade"),
                                        a.getString("Atividade"),
                                        java.sql.Date.valueOf(a.getString("dataPrevista")),
                                        java.sql.Time.valueOf(a.getString("hora")),
                                        a.getString("Destinatarios"),
                                        a.getString("Local")
                                ));
                            }
                            AtividadesAdapter mAdapter = new AtividadesAdapter(AtividadesActivity.this, atividadesList);
                            recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    }
                });
        Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(stringRequest);
    }
}
```

Everytime i'm trying to start the app, i get this error.
I have already change the xml files to match with the examples provided here but still have no success.

Comment: Yo get which error ?

Comment: Create and attach empty adapter to recyclerView before calling to loadAtividades. When you have data , set data to adapter

Comment: E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

Comment: Maya....do you have an exmaple please?

Comment: You need to attach adapter before getting the data.

Comment: It happens whenever your adapter doesn't get the dataset and return null values from the adapter which you've attached with the recyclerview. Make sure you're setting up the adapter with null checking validation. This might helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please attach parent and the rest:

```
@Override
public Holder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    return new AtividadesViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(mCtx).inflate(R.layout.atividades_lista, parent, false));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question and the code I think this will help you.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.atividadesrecyclerview);
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        AtividadesAdapter mAdapter = new AtividadesAdapter(getApplicationContext, atividadesList);
         recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        loadAtividades();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add to your adapter:

```
public AtividadesAdapter(Context mCtx) {
    this.mCtx = mCtx;
}

public void setItems(@NonNull final List<Atividades> items) {

    if (atividadesList != null) {
        atividadesList.clear();
    } else {
        atividadesList = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    atividadesList.addAll(items);
}
```

onCreate of the activity should be as follows:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.atividadesrecyclerview);
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mAdapter = new AtividadesAdapter(AtividadesActivity.this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    loadAtividades();
}
```

In loadAtividades() call to setItems:

```
mAdapter.setItems(atividadesList);
```